# Deixar div e elementos fixos

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho div que abre para a lateral ao clicar no botão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu deixar a div com "Mudar de cidade" com height fixo até resolve, mas as letras continuam a se mexer.

Teria alguma forma de os elementos não se redimensionassem ao abrir?

Comment: Como assim continuam a se mexer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na div q contém a animação coloque:

```
div{
   overflow:hidden;
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Isso vai fazer com o que estiver dentro da sua div fique do tamanho dela, sem se redimensionar.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Um elemento fixo - fixed - é posicionado relativamente ao "viewport", isso significa que ele sempre ficará no mesmo lugar mesmo que haja rolagem na página.
 Assim como o relative, as propriedades `top`, `right`, `bottom` e `left` também são utilizadas.

Tenho certeza que você notou um elemento fixo no canto direito da tela, estou te dando a permissão de observá-lo agora, e aqui está o CSS aplicado a ele:

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}

<div class="fixed">
    Oi! eu estou fixo
</div>
```